# CakePHP: Get loggedin user data

Tags: cakephp, authentication, userinfo

**What I did**

I used this part of the Cookbook to create my authentication: Link
After i was finished, i changed the fields to email and password (in AppController.php):

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    $this->Auth->allow('index');
    $this->Auth->fields = array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password');
}
```

**What happened**

The login form always said that my password/email combination was not correct.
After a while searching and trying stuff, i added "$this->request->data" to the Auth->login() parameter in the login() function of the UsersController:

```
public function login(){
    $this->layout = 'login';
    if ($this->request->is('post')){
        if ($this->Auth->login($this->request->data)){
            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Ongeldig email adres of wachtwoord. Probeer het AUB opnieuw'));
        }
    }
}
```

This worked, but now i can't use "$user['id']" to get the loggedin users id. It says that it doesn't know the $user variable.

**What I expected to happen**

In the first place, it should have logged the user in without me adding the parameter. And second, it should have printed the loggedin user's id.

I hope someone can help me with the problem.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$this->Auth->login($this->request->data)` => the worst thing you could possibly do here. remove that right away. it is the same as 1=1 - nonsense for authenticated logins!

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#accessing-the-logged-in-user

Comment: Which CakePHP version are you using? Since 2.2 you have to do what @mark say in his answer.

Comment: I use CakePHP 2.2.3. But i had to add $this->request->data bacause the Auth->login() would otherwise return false, which it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

fields is now in the authenticate array:

```
   'authenticate' => array(
        'Form' => array(
            'fields' => array('username' => 'email', ...)
        )
    )
```

see
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html#configuring-authentication-handlers

either with

```
$this->Auth->authenticate = ...
```

or

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        'authenticate' => ...
    )
);
```

but, as PHP freelancer stated, this is well documented.

what cookbook version did you use? the 2.x one?

Comment: Yes, i used the 2.x version. I will try it again tomorrow, thanks for the help already ;)

Comment: I changed the $components to:
`public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array('userModel' => 'User', 'fields' => array('username' => 'email', 'password' => 'password'))
            ),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'twitter', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authorize' => array('Controller')
        )
    );`
But now it just goes to the login redirect while the account doesnt exist.